# Merging smaller XML into single XML

Tags: c#, xml

We have a large xml document which will be in kb's downloading it is taking almost 1 hr, eventually end up with request time out issue in production.What am thinking to do is instead of constructing entire xml at once i want to construct in smaller chunks and merge it as a final parent xml based on nodes  is there any way to do it.

Comment: have a look at LINQ to XML

Comment: You should compress file before downloading.  Xml is text which compress very well.  You could get less than 1/3 of the file size by compressing.

Comment: we are doing compression this happens after compression only

Answer (score 0):

I hope you use HTTP (or HTTPS) protocol to download the file? That way, you can try to download it by ranges: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests

HTTP ranges would give you exactly what you want, without messing with split/merge logic by hand. Besides, that feature was wide-spread at dial-up modems age (that were prone to drop the connection randomly, and overall throughput was hardly 30-40 kilobytes per second). It seems it's a good time to re-invent HTTP ranges back for the large-size content, isn't it?